# Warning message: In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo

Tags: r

Have the following warning message as " Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
There were missing values in resampled performance measures."  After compiling this row of code

Comment: Hi, please, add the minimal code to reproduce the error. If you need help providing such code, I recommend this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/10264278

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.